# Can't find a second google analytics code that's causing conflicts

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I have a strange situation: I have a Wordpress site which includes an area to paste analytics code. I've done so. However, we're getting messages from google saying there is a tracking code mismatch. After calling Google we viewed the page source of the site and the SECOND analytics code is indeed there. It's preventing the REAL analytics code from firing. I just want to remove it.

However, there is only one place to put the tracking code in my site and that's where I've put the valid tracking code. I use Dreamweaver for my FTP stuff and have done a site-wide search for this extra analytics code and NOTHING shows up.

I've checked header.php, footer.php, index.php separately. The only thing I see is PHP code saying place analytics code here (i.e. from the theme options).

Where the hell is this second script and how can I find and delete it? Thanks for any help. I'm pulling my hair out about this.

Comment: whereabouts on the source is the second google code block placed? right after the first on in a different "area"?

Answer (score 0):

Is the second/invalid analytics code appearing right above or below the first? Or is it in an entirely different area in the source code?

It may be a bug with the Wordpress theme you're using, or you might have a plugin enabled that has some predefined settings for inserting Analytics code. It might even be a widget. You could try disabling your theme/plugins to troubleshoot.

Temporary solution would be to remove the code from the Wordpress backend and add it into header.php or footer.php manually.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone else who may experience the same thing, I swapped out my WP theme for a default one. Then switched back. I didn't need to disable plugins as lachesis suggested since the "correct" tracking code reappeared in the page source. I can only surmise that it was the theme itself that for some reason stored the extra tracking code and that it was never "flushed" out when I reentered the correct code.